# Stream Builder is not Working, navigation error

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test, stream-builder

Stream Builder is not functioning: I want it to move to the next page when user logged in.

I receive token against the email that is used to log in but navigation not performed by Stream Builder.

This is Main.dart:

```
class _ThisAppState extends State<ThisApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: _handleWindowDisplay(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
Widget _handleWindowDisplay() {
  StreamBuilder(
      stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged,
      builder: (context, asyncSnapshot) {
        if (asyncSnapshot.hasError) {
          return new Text("Error!");
        } else if (asyncSnapshot.data == null) {
          return new LoginPage();
        } else {
          if (asyncSnapshot.data.state) {
            return new LoginPage();
          } else
            return MainScreen();
        }
      },);
}


class _ThisAppState extends State<ThisApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: _handleWindowDisplay(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
Widget _handleWindowDisplay() {
  StreamBuilder(
      stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged,
      builder: (context, asyncSnapshot) {
        if (asyncSnapshot.hasError) {
          return new Text("Error!");
        } else if (asyncSnapshot.data == null) {
          return new LoginPage();
        } else {
          if (asyncSnapshot.data.state) {
            return new LoginPage();
          } else
            return MainScreen();
        }
      },);
}


**Login Screen**

import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  String _email,_Password;

  FutureOr Function(AuthResult value) get onValue => null;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child:
        Form(child:
        Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            TextFormField(decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Enter Email"),
            onChanged: (value){
              this.setState((){_email=value;});
            },
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 10,),
            TextFormField(decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Enter Password"),
            onChanged:(value) {
              this.setState(() {
                _Password = value;
              });
            },
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 10,),
            RaisedButton(child: Text("Sign In"),onPressed: ()=>{
              FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: _email, password: _Password)
            .then((onValue){

              }).catchError((error){
              debugPrint("The error is "+error);
            })
            })
    ],

        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Navigator.push() method.

For example to move to your MainScreen(), you need to use below code.

```
Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MainScreen()),
  );
```

You should checkout [Navigation Basics](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics)

Comment: Will this work just in case when a user is already logged in?

Comment: mean to say, auto navigation

Comment: Yes it will work as stream will always notify the corresponding streambuilder whenever changes takes place.

Comment: StreamBuilder(
      stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged,
      builder: (BuildContext context,snapshot){
        if (snapshot.connectionState==ConnectionState.waiting) {
          print("Waiting state");
          return Scaffold(
            body: Container(child: Text("Waiting state"),)
          );
        }  else {

          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MainScreen()),
            );
          }else {
            return LoginPage();
        }  }
      });

Answer (score 0):

I think _handleWindowDisplay() should return streambuilder instead of just widgets that are returned by StreamBuilder

```
Widget _handleWindowDisplay() {
 return StreamBuilder(
  stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged,
  builder: (context, asyncSnapshot) {
    if (asyncSnapshot.hasError) {
      return new Text("Error!");
    } else if (asyncSnapshot.data == null) {
      return new LoginPage();
    } else {
      if (asyncSnapshot.data.state) {
        return new LoginPage();
      } else
        return MainScreen();
    }
  },);
}
```